# Why does my iframe disappear and what can i do about it?

Tags: javascript, jquery

My main goal is that i want to automate actions in web browsers. for instance click or follow links, put text in. via core programming (no software) do you have suggestions i can try?

--

I wanted to ask you some question as i just started programming my first javascript/jquery so excuse me if you find me total newb. i just want to learn ;)

I try to figure this out since last night and today but i can't find an answer searched all if the internet no result. total time: 5 hours...

Why o why does my iframe disappear and how can i solve this to learn.

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Q</title>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<iframe id="google1" width="100%" height="600" src="https://www.google.nl/intl/en/about/products/"></iframe>

<script type="text/javascript">
document.getElementById('google1').onload = function() 
{
 $('<a href="https://www.google.com/intl/en/mail/help/about.html#utm_source=en-et-more&utm_medium=et&utm_campaign=en">Gmail</a>')[0].click();
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You're trying to click on the gmail-link inside the iFrame? This will not work due to cross-origin restriction. If the source of your iFrame is not on your own server, then you can't access the content via javascript. However I can navigate in the iFrame, it stays where it is in your example

Comment: Thank you for your kind reply.

Comment: My main goal is that i want to automate actions in web browsers. for instance click or follow links, put text in. via core programming (no software) do you have suggestions i can try?

Comment: This script will be run locally

Comment: If this is for personal use, there are browser addons for most browsers that allow some JS to be executed on page load. e.g. Greasemonkey for FireFox.